# How to use ImageMagick convert in php to replace a color?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick in the commandline to replace a color with this :

```
convert input.jpg -fuzz 5% -fill red -opaque 'rgba(176,180,182, 1.0)' output.jpg
```

How would I do this in php?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With PHP's [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), opaque method [`Imageick::opaquePaintImage`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.opaquepaintimage.php) can be used.

```php
$img = new Imagick('source.png');
$target = 'rgba(176,180,182, 1.0)';
$fill = 'red';
$fuzz = 0.05 * $img->getQuantumRange()['quantumRangeLong'];
$img->opaquePaintImage($target, $fill, $fuzz, false, Imagick::CHANNEL_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: While this looks OK and does not produce any errors, for some reason I am not getting the desired output as with the command line. It only does something if I change false o true, but that fills the whole image red. Any idea?

Comment: My bad @eemceebee. Updated answer. Any 'percent' value must be calculated from image's quantum range. So if my system is on Q16, then 5% would be `65535 * 0.05 = 3276.75`.

Comment: thanks, this works. I definitely have to read up on the quantum range because I certainly have no clue what this is doing and why. Thanks again.

Comment: What is min and max for fuzz? Nothing in the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.opaquepaintimage.php